# How to change the alt text on input validation

Tags: html, validation

I have a very simple form with an input field and a submit button:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="number" min="1" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

When typing in "0" in the input field and submitting the form, a validation error message is displayed. I also noticed the alt-text is set to the same validation message when I hover over the invalid input field. Is it possible to change the alt-text and how do you do it?

Comment: See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an id to the element to make it easy to refer to in the javascript:

```
<form action="#">
    <input id="num" type="number" min="1" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

document.getElementById('num').alt = 'your text here'
document.getElementById('num').title = 'your text here'
```

It might also be useful to set the title (popup text) in addition to the alt text (text displayed if the image can't be loaded).

Comment: The input element is not an image, it is a number. Setting the alt property does not change the validation message

Comment: Your question was about how to change the alt text. If you're trying to change the popup text, you should be changing the title attribute.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your answer - when setting the title it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 constraint validation API might be a better solution, as in Chrome, at least, changing "title" attribute does not chage the error message entirely, but partly. You can use setCustomValidity() method like that

```
<form action="#">
   <input id="num" type="number" min="1" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

document.getElementById('num').setCustomValidity('your full message text here')
```